# Get region sales along with state in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL Server. I have a table with columns `Region`, `State` and `Sales` - like this:

| Region | State | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| East | California | 100 |
| East | texas | 200 |
| West | roseland | 100 |
| West | Newjerea | 200 |

I need to show region-wise sales along with state-wise sales in the same query.

Could any one please help how to do this?

Comment: please show the expected result and also your attempt

Comment: Please read [mre] and then add your desired results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rollup with group by clause like below to get region wise, state wise and total sales summary:

Query:

```
select region, state,sum(sales) [total sale]
from SalesData
group by region,state
  with rollup
order by region,state
```

Output:

| region | state | total sale |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *null* | *null* | 600 |
| East | *null* | 300 |
| East | California | 100 |
| East | Texas | 200 |
| West | *null* | 300 |
| West | NewJersey | 200 |
| West | Roseland | 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lCGtzawZ)

Or you can use window function sum()over() to get the region-wise sales like below:

Query:

```
select region,sum(sales)over(partition by region)[region wise total sale],state,sales
from SalesData
```

Output:

| region | region wise total sale | state | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| East | 300 | California | 100 |
| East | 300 | Texas | 200 |
| West | 300 | Roseland | 100 |
| West | 300 | NewJersey | 200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/SlgpNcSt)

Comment: Hi kazi mohammad , I need to get sales for state also in the same query.Could you please help

Comment: @vissubabu Sure! Please share your desired output format.

Comment: @vissubabu These already included state wide sales. Please be specific in what you want (edit your question to include example desired output) and specific in why this doesn't meet your requirements.